# COM Local Server

Tags: com

Similar to LocalServer32, which is used to specify the path to a 32Bit Local COM server, is there any registry entry for specifying the path to a 64Bit Local COM Server?

If there is none, can we use LocalServer32 for 64Bit servers also?

Note: In my knowledge there are only 2 registry entries - LocalServer and LocalServer32. According to MSDN the former is used for registering 16bit server and the latter to register a 32bit server.

Thanks and Regards,

Gamer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The registry on 64bit has [registry redirection and/or reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384253.aspx) so there can be two LocalServer32 entries (A 32bit process would see the entry under Wow6432Node, and a 64 bit process would see the "true" entry) If the applications that registers your COM server is 32bit, you need to [turn off](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/aa384129(v=VS.85).aspx) the registry redirection when writing the 64bit entry

Comment: Hi Anders, Thank you for your reply. 

But, after creating the registry key, i found that changing the value in the 64Bit registry hive (so that it points to the 64bit version of the server) also changes the value in the wow6432node hive (which originally pointed to the the 32bit version of the server). Any idea why this might be happening?